# Como excluir chave primária (PK) no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-primária

Tenho a seguinte tabela no MySQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna id é chave primária. Eu gostaria de retirar a chave primária dessa tabela. Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute essa query para retirar a coluna desejada:

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` DROP `coluna`;
```

Vejo que é iniciante no **PT StackOverflow**, mas realmente é necessário retirar a chave primária de sua tabela? Analise bem seu caso, ela é necessária para diferenciar os registros, assim tendo algo que os torne realmente únicos, extremamente importante e necessária para `UPDATES` e `DELETES`, cada caso é um caso, mas antes de retirá-la, veja se isso realmente é necessário como eu já disse.

E caso queira apenas fazer um `SELECT` de modo que essa coluna não apareça, é simples, só mandar um: `SELECT nome, profissao, nascimento, sexo, peso, altura, nacionalidade FROM tabela WHERE...`

Por último, para apenas retirar a função de chave primária você deve executar essas duas querys:

```
//Você deve primeiro remover a propriedade de AUTO_INCREMENT e depois
//remover a chave primária

ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE tabela DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Para que ela volte a ser chave primária é só executar:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Para retirar a chave primária só excluindo a coluna? Não é possível eu retirar o primary key sem excluir a coluna?

Comment: @AlexBorges é como eu disse, você quer retirá-la da tabela ou apenas que ela não apareça em um `SELECT`? Se for a segunda opção, use o que eu disse no segundo parágrafo

Comment: @AlexBorges Ou você quer apenas que ela deixe de ser a chave primária dentro da tabela?

Comment: Quero que ela apenas deixe de ser a chave primária dentro da tabela.

Comment: @AlexBorges vou modificar a resposta, veja agora

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.

Comment: Quando você executa o SQL: "ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna INT NOT NULL;", você retira o auto-incremento da coluna, isso?

Comment: @AlexBorges sim, primeiro o `AUTO_INCREMENT` deve ser retirado pra depois a função de chave primária

Comment: @AlexBorges se isso resolver seu problema, por favor, marque a reposta como aceita :), assim outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida também poderão saná-las mais

Comment: Estou tendo problemas com minha conta. Assim que eu resolver, marco sua resposta como aceita. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Apaga a PK:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela DROP CONSTRAINT pk;
```

Recria a PK sem a coluna a ser retirada:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY (CONSTRAINT pk primary key (coluna1, coluna2, ...));
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).